# Dados de um RecyclerView Selecionado

Tags: java, android, json, android-layout

Boa tarde,

Preciso que quando a pessoa clique em um pegue os dados do AnimeActivity e seja passado para tela IniciarRelatorio, alguém conseguiria me ajudar ?

[inserir a descrição da imagem aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDO8i.png)
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá, vc está criando um objeto AnimeActivity, para receber o objeto que foi "Serializado".
Sendo que vc enviou o objeto Anime.
Altera na linha 28 da classe Iniciar visita:

```
Anime anime = (Anime) intent.getSerializableExtra("extra_anime");
```

**--------------EDIT**

Desculpe o equivoco, não tinha me atentado que vc está passando apenas um String para a Activity.
Vamos aproveitar, para conferir se seu código está realmente passando o dado e certificarmos de não apresentar nenhum `Exception`:

```
txtContrato = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_contrato); 
Intent intent = getIntent();
String anime = (String) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("extra_anime");
if (anime != null){
    txtContrato.setText(anime);
}
```

**------ Update 05/10**

Se puder, copie o código da AnimeActivity inteira. Pois, por imagem, gera muita confusão. Por exemplo, a primeira e segunda imagem, são do mesmo trecho. Porém, o código está diferente.

Se você quer enviar apenas o texto, para a outra Activity. Na terceira imagem, onde está a chamada da IniciarVisita.  Linha 57, altere para:

```
String anime = tv_name.getText().toString();
```

Mas lembre-se de mudar a sua assinatura do putExtra "extra_anime". Pois, vai deixar o seu código mais complicado de ler. Já que esta Activity já está recebendo esta mesma assinatura, em um objeto "anime".

Dito isso, se preferir, ao invés de enviar apenas o String. Você pode remover esta linha de declaração e utilize o objeto declarado na linha 41 "anime". Aproveite para modificar ela para ser uma variável global da classe. Para concluir, na IniciarVisita e retorne para fazer o cast na linha 28, para:

```
Anime anime = (Anime) intent.getSerializableExtra("extra_anime");
```

Comment: Ai ficaria exemplo:         Intent intent = getIntent();
        Anime anime = (Anime) intent.getSerializableExtra("extra_anime");
        txtContrato.setText(anime.getName());

Comment: SIM. Lembre-se apenas, que o setText, vai dar NullPointer, caso vc não tenha declarado o campo txtContrato. Utilizando o findViewById.

Comment: Esta dando esse erro: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.demotxt.myapp.RelatorioBR.model.Anime.getName()' on a null object reference
        at com.demotxt.myapp.RelatorioBR.visitas.IniciarVisita.onCreate(IniciarVisita.java:39)

Comment: meu código ta assim:                                                                                                                                  txtContrato = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_contrato);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Anime anime = (Anime) intent.getSerializableExtra("extra_anime");
        txtContrato.setText(anime.getName());

Comment: Rodrigo boa tarde, agora o codigo está funcionando OK mas não apresenta nenhum valor, preciso que pegue o anime.getName selecionado na Recycler View seria possível conversamos via WPP ou alguma outra forma remota pra você me ajudar a dar uma luz ?